# Delete folder with invalid character (-encoding)

Tags: files, filenames, rm, character-encoding

On my Linux Mint 18.3 installation I had troubles with my locale setting which caused the generation of a folder that has invalid encoding in its name.

I would now like to delete said folder but I can't figure out how I can do so. I tried using my file manager (Dolphin) as well as the terminal (`sudo rmdir <folder name>`) but both commands failed claiming that the given folder doesn't exist.

However, it still gets displayed in the file manager and via the `ls` command.

```
sudo rmdir Einf�hrung in die Biochemie/
rmdir: failed to remove 'Einf�hrung': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'in': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'die': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'Biochemie/': No such file or directory
```

The name of the directory was copied from the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `*`

```
sudo rm -rfi Ein*
```

or

```
sudo rm -rfi *Biochemie
```

Provided there are no other directories that match the pattern, in which case you'll have to pick a pattern that's unique.

You could also use `rmdir` instead of `rm`.

As [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) pointed out, the `-i` option will help if the pattern matches directories which are not to be deleted(by prompting for confirmation on each match).

Comment: The -i option might be nice.

Comment: Good point, let me add it...

Comment: That does indeed seem like a good solution as well. However in my case I had a directory called `Einführung in die Biochemie` as well so it might be a little tricky for that case. But for a "normal" case this seems like a very solid solution.

Comment: @Raven this will work in your case as well. `*` matches anything. I've had to use it with cyrilic and chinese characters and it works like charm.

Comment: Yeah I know... Should have added that I actually did *not* want the `Einführung in die Biochemie` folder to be deleted ^^

Comment: @Raven you can do `sudo rm -rfi *` and manually pick the ones to get deleted and the ones not to(assuming you have a few files to iterate over).

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, a visual file manager like Thunar is quite handy.

If your system hasn't a GUI, tools like the midnight-commander help a lot.

In simple cases, using command completion might be sufficient.

```
 rm -i Einf→→
```

where the → shall symbolize the Tab-key, or, like ManOv showed, maybe an Wildcard is enough:

```
 rm 'Einf?hrung in die Biochemie'
 rm 'Einf*hrung in die Biochemie'
```

If you're not allowed to install such modern stuff, find might help:

With

```
ls -la Ein*
```

you can investigate file attributes, like size, modification time, owner, attributes, ... to feed to find:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Einf*hrung *chemie" -mtime -4 -mtime +2 -size +2000 -size -2200
```

If the result is just that one specific file, add the delete switch. This works not with all sorts of find, but with GNU-find:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Einf*hrung *chemie" -mtime -4 -mtime +2 -size +2000 -size -2200 -delete
```

For other find versions, you'll find a lot of examples, how to delete files, here, too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rename all other files and folder in the parent directory of said dir that also started with `Ein` e.g. by prefixing them with a `1_` and then go in the terminal type in `sudo rmdir Ein` and hitting tab to let the autocomplete-fuction do the rest for me.
That actually resolved the characters accordingly so that I was finally able to delete the directory with that command.